# call jar file method in Activity class Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a jar file which want to use in my android app. I know how to run jar file in terminal. I also know that I should add those jar files to android projects in lib folder.
I don't know how to call Main method of specific jar file in Activity class. Also there are many jar files that are interdepended.

Answer (score 1):

Library has to be added in app level build.gradle file after stored in lib folder. For instance:
`implementation files('libs/print.jar')`. Then you can import the class inside this jar file like any other class and call public or static methods. Correct me if I am wrong, please.